# In jQuery, how can I in an each loop remove array elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's say I have an array :

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

and I'm looping them with jQuery.each:

```
$(arr).each(function(index, value){
    if (somethingIsTrue){
        // Based on if "somethingIsTrue" I want to remove this particular item from the array at this point
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how about creating a new array with the elements that satisfies somethingIsTrue?

Comment: `pop` only removes the last element in the array.

Comment: Sachin, I know you didn't answer the question but I ended up going with your solution instead. Much easier to just append new values to the new array.

Comment: @Weblurk It should be noted that the accepted answer will not work correctly if the array has more than one item that matches the specified condition. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zdjqh8om/2/

Comment: plz see updated answer..as per your question first answer will work absolutely fine but for case specified in above fiddle link try my second answer.

Comment: @Kartikeya Your new answer still suffers from the same kind of bug, and you've now got a worst-case running time complexity of O(N^2): http://jsfiddle.net/zdjqh8om/5 Will you please just admit that removing (or adding) elements in an array while iterating through it is a bad idea, even if you can get the right result some of the time?

Comment: plz read answer carefully..third answer..since questioner not mentioned all the cases in question so i posted three answers for all the conditions.covered.. @JLRishe

Comment: @JLRishe..if its something you didn't understand feel free to ask..

Comment: @Kartikeya I wrote that comment referring to your second answer and before you posted the third one. The third one is fine, though I suggest deleting the other two because they are buggy.

Comment: @JLRishe...i have posted comment above that ... since questioner didn't posted all conditions in question according to the question if number donot repeat...my first two answers also will work absolutely fine.

Comment: @Kartikeya Even if they "work fine" for a limited set of inputs, they're still bad answers.

Comment: @JLRishe...i don't think its bad answer for you i have put a note in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var arr1 = []   //make a separate array to store numbers fulfilling specified condition

$.each(arr,function(i,v){
    if(somethingIsTrue){
    arr1.push(v)  //fill second array with required numbers fulfilling specified condition
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5prbgb68/)

OR

```
var arr = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8];
var filteredarr = $.map(arr,function (value,index) {
  return (somethingIsTrue ? value : null)
});
```

`'filteredarr'` will be a another array having numbers satisfying the condition.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjqh8om/6/)

OR

Try `.splice()` as shown :

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

$(arr).each(function(index, value){
  if(somethingIsTrue){
    arr.splice(index,1)
  }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjqh8om/)

OR

```
$.each(arr,function(i,v){
  if(somethingIsTrue){
  var i1 = arr.indexOf(v);
    arr.splice(i1,1);
  }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjqh8om/3/)

**NOTE :- Last two answers will work absolutely fine if array do not contains repeating numbers(as questioner specified in question) and first two answers will work in any scenario.**

Comment: You shouldn't use `$(arr)` with an array of numbers. Also, even if it works, I think it's not a good idea to remove elements from an array while you are iterating through it.

Comment: the above shown answer is absolutely correct...its arr only not $(arr) .. i m removing specified element from arr only..and please  downvote if answer is not correct and not on your personnal opinion that 'its not a good idea'..@JLRishe

Comment: I'm not sure how you are trying to claim that you're not using `$(arr)`, when there's an `$(arr)` in your code, plain as day. On that point, your post is incontrovertibly incorrect. Aside from that, anyone has the prerogative to downvote answers that are using bad practices, and removing elements from an array while iterating through it is a bad practice.

Comment: @JLRishe..i just remove the specified element from array when it just iterated already...so its not a problem..and moreover i have specified the fiddle link also just test it as many times as you want.

Comment: Actually, it very much is a problem. Please see here to observe your code producing a completely wrong result: http://jsfiddle.net/zdjqh8om/1/

Comment: that is different scenario which you have showed inside fiddle..@JLRishe

Comment: No it isn't. OP wants to remove items that match a certain condition. Your code only works if there's only one such item. Just because your code works for a single example input, that doesn't mean that it works.

Comment: @JLRishe..okk..i don't want to fight over here..its depends on questioner requirement completely and its upto questioner that which answer will he accept..thanks..

Comment: Fine. But in any case, `$(arr)` is wrong and you should fix it. If you're not sure how, feel free to read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with the way you're trying to go about this. You shouldn't use `$(arr)` on an array of numbers, and you shouldn't remove elements from an array while you are iterating through it. That's a surefire recipe for buggy code.

Instead of jQuery and `each()`, you should use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (you can also use `$.grep()` if you need to support older browsers or absolutely want to use jQuery):

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function (value) {
    return !somethingIsTrue;
});
```

After this is called, `filtered` will be an array containing all the items where `somethingIsTrue` is not true (which is what I think you are asking for).

As stated above, jQuery `each` is not the tool to use here, but in general you should only use `$(arr)` when `arr` contains only DOM elements. To iterate over an ordinary array in jQuery, use `$.each(arr, callback)`.

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtbq1fpk/)

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle, 
http://jsfiddle.net/devools/35aysq6t/

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];


$(arr).each(function (index, value) {
    if (value = 2) {
        arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
            return value != 2;
        });
    }
});

$(arr).each(function (index, value) {
    $('.array').append(value + ',');
});
```

Comment: `if (value = 2)` will always execute its body. Also, this seems like a rather convoluted (and incorrect) way to accomplish this.